# Definition of factorial function

Tags: factorial

Is there a definition of the factorial function (for natural numbers) in the language of ordered rings?

Comment: If the ring is a domain of zero characteristic you can embed $\Bbb Z$ inside it and use the usual definition. Or do you mean for every (possible) element of the ring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the ring has a suitably nice measure defined on it, you might be able to adopt [the Gamma or Pi functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial#The_Gamma_and_Pi_functions) as your notion of factorial.